# SSRS expression throws #Error - any reasons?

Tags: reporting-services, ssrs-2008, reportingservices-2005

I am new to the SSRS This is expression i am trying but it's showing **"#Error"** i tried varies things but still not any progress any guess why might it's happening.

```
=IIF(Fields!MailMeans.Value = "M","METER",
  IIF(Fields!MailMeans.Value = "I","INDICIA",
    IIF(Fields!MailMeans.Value = "S","STAMPS",
        IIF(Fields!MailMeans.Value = "N","NO-MAIL","")
        )
    )
 )
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using `Switch` rather than the nested `IIF`

```
=Switch(Fields!MailMeans.Value = "M", "METER", 
        Fields!MailMeans.Value = "I", "INDICIA", 
        Fields!MailMeans.Value = "S", "STAMPS")
```

Comment: how to add the default case in switch that is "

Answer (score 0):

This should also work:

`=Switch(Fields!MailMeans.Value = "M", "METER",
        Fields!MailMeans.Value = "I", "INDICIA", 
        Fields!MailMeans.Value = "S", "STAMPS",
        Fields!MailMeans.Value = "N", "NO-MAIL",
        Fields!MailMeans.Value <> "M" AND Fields!MailMeans.Value <> "I" AND
        Fields!MailMeans.Value <> "S" AND Fields!MailMeans.Value <> "N", "")`